# Android device not recognized in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, mtp

I was trying to connect my Android phone to my laptop as an MTP device. Two days ago I had tried it and it had worked fine. 
This time it was recognized in PTP mode but not in MTP. I ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Then I realized that if I connected the phone on the usb port of the other side it gets recognized and everything ran fine. But then I decided to do something dumb and I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
sudo apt-get remove mtpfs`
```

And then the phone wasn't recognized anymore, not even as a PTP device. I ran again,

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

but that didn't solve the issue.